# Какие параметры должны быть у устройств чтобы можно было тестировать различные density?

Tags: java, android, density

У разных устройств могут быть различные плотности пикселей.

Хотел бы понять - какие параметры нужно создать для каждой плотности, чтобы можно было проверить корректную работу и исправить ошибки отображения ( в случае их появления)

Привожу код всех значений density

```
   public static String getDeviceDensityString(Context context) {
switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
        return "ldpi";
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
        return "mdpi";
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        return "hdpi";
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_260:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_280:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
        return "xhdpi";
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_340:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_360:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_400:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_420:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_440:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
        return "xxhdpi";
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_560:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
        return "xxxhdpi";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ldpi - 240x360

mdpi - 320х480

hdpi - 480x720

xhdpi - 640x960

xxhdpi - 960x1440

xxxhdpi - 1280x1920